# iOS 10, APNS and Binary Provider API

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, http2

How do I set the new APNS collapse ID field introduced on iOS 10 using the legacy Binary Provider API?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Appendixes/BinaryProviderAPI.html

If you look at table A-3 on this page, you won't see support for apns-collapse-id.

apns-collapse-id is something new to update/remove existing notification using an identifier.

Is Apple going to deprecate or remove Binary Provider API soon as Apple requests developers to migrate to HTTP/2 on the same page?

With regards to iOS 10, is it required for me to migrate to HTTP/2 to send push notifications to APNS?

Comment: I thought the binary provider API was already deprecated

Comment: No, not yet. I sent a push message to my phone a minute ago using it.

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean turned off, it just means "not preferred" and you are discouraged from using it. Refer to the first sentence in this document - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Appendixes/BinaryProviderAPI.html - new features aren't added to the binary provider API

Comment: I agree. For some reason, Apple's HTTP/2 documentation does not have apns-collapse-id though I used it using a 3rd party library called pushy to collapse notifications sent to a device running on iOS 10. Need to see if Apple updates their Binary API supporting it (I don't think this will happen) or I got to move to HTTP/2 :)

Comment: According to this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50606 it is not in the payload, it is a http header, so I would say it won't be added to the binary API.

Comment: Yes, it is a header. But there are other fields in Binary API and their equivalents are headers in HTTP/2. Example: expiration date (4 bytes) and  apns-expiration (HTTP header for HTTP/2).